# Convert a CURL output of tabular data into a json array in PHP or via CLI command?

Tags: php, json, curl, command-line-interface

I'm trying to see what is the best method of converting a CURL output of tabular data as seen below into JSON.

I'm running:

```
curl -d "sql query here" -X POST https://xxx/database_query
```

Currently the output has | as the separator and I need to slice off the first line because its displaying the query string. I was thinking to pass this data through sed to clean it up a bit first?

```
> select ID, HEIGHT, COIN_BALANCE from account order by balance desc limit 20
ID                   | HEIGHT  | COIN_BALANCE
-7700097703553861699 | 1815934 | 299014795
-354651164223319404  | 1789433 | 150010434
514812057486191450   | 1815934 | 150000409
2819400133805325807  | 1789617 | 150000289
2045072049257519302  | 0       | 150000000
2825154884517497903  | 0       | 17904059
```

Comment: Paste as text not as screenshot.

Comment: updated to text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create an array by exploding of line breaks
- Drop first row
- Get next row with fieldnames, exploding by pipe and trim each
- Loop over the rest and put it mapped with fieldnames into a new array, explode by pipe and trim each
- Convert the results into JSON

```
$fromCurl = <<<'_EOT'
> select ID, HEIGHT, COIN_BALANCE from account order by balance desc limit 20
ID                   | HEIGHT  | COIN_BALANCE
-7700097703553861699 | 1815934 | 299014795
-354651164223319404  | 1789433 | 150010434
514812057486191450   | 1815934 | 150000409
2819400133805325807  | 1789617 | 150000289
2045072049257519302  | 0       | 150000000
2825154884517497903  | 0       | 17904059
_EOT;

$data = explode("\n", $fromCurl);
$firstLine = array_shift($data);
$fieldnames = array_map('trim', explode('|', array_shift($data)));

$result = [];
foreach($data as $line) {
    $values = array_map('trim', explode('|', $line));
    $result[] = array_combine($fieldnames, $values);
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

prints

```
[
    {
        "ID": "-7700097703553861699",
        "HEIGHT": "1815934",
        "COIN_BALANCE": "299014795"
    },
    {
        "ID": "-354651164223319404",
        "HEIGHT": "1789433",
        "COIN_BALANCE": "150010434"
    },
    {
        "ID": "514812057486191450",
        "HEIGHT": "1815934",
        "COIN_BALANCE": "150000409"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2819400133805325807",
        "HEIGHT": "1789617",
        "COIN_BALANCE": "150000289"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2045072049257519302",
        "HEIGHT": "0",
        "COIN_BALANCE": "150000000"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2825154884517497903",
        "HEIGHT": "0",
        "COIN_BALANCE": "17904059"
    }
]
```